# Python AttributeError not catching

Tags: python, exception, getattr

I have some code where i'm trying to catch an exception and stifle it, but no matter what I do the code never prints the statement in the except block.

```
def check_configuration(cls, **kwargs):
    print 'product_config'
    errors = {}
    for arg in kwargs:
        if arg in cls.get_fields():
            print 'found', arg
            try:
                getattr(cls, 'clean_'+arg)
            except:
                print 'missing validation method: clean_'+attr+'()'
```

'missing validation method: clean_la()' never prints!

I have tried

```
except Exception:

except AttributeError:
```

they don't work either, I'm confused is there something I'm missing with exceptions?

Comment: Does it print "found" at all? It might not be reaching the Try block?

Comment: Your exception handling seems correct, I guess you are never reaching it, though.

Comment: Yes it prints found, only excepts in the try block

Comment: is it possible that some other part of my program is catching the exception before this except block?

Comment: where is the `attr` variable in the `except` declared ?

Comment: good spot! that must be it! thanks

Comment: Can you please check if `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` of your `cls` overridden to handle this kind situation ?

Answer (score 0):

this is solved thanks to Shadow, the problem was in the except method.

attr is never defined.

```
print 'missing validation method: clean_'+attr+'()'
```